# Letting a bootstrap `b-dropdown` escape out of an `overflow:scroll` container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ronj/t6z6Lnfb/) you'll see a typical {left sidebar + right content} layout, made using Bootstrap 4 {`container-fluid`, `row`, `col`}.

- In the *left sidebar* live a set of filters. It may contain several filters that will consume undetermined vertical space, thus lives in an `overflow-y:scroll` div. Each filter has a dropdown which lets users modify filter options.
- In the *right pane* lives the content, filtered by the filters in the left sidebar.

Now, click the `Filter 1` (Bootstrap4-based) dropdown in the sidebar and notice how it is unusable due to being unable to "escape" out of its `overflow-y:scroll` parent.

**→ Question**: How can I keep that `overflow-y:scroll` sidebar scrolling behavior (which I need because there can be many filters), while letting the dropdown items (which can be large, both in width and height) "escape out of" / not be constrained by the sidebar?

**EDIT** Looks like vanilla `<select>` don't suffer from this problem. Sadly, I'm using a few features from `<b-dropdown>` that I will lose if I go back to vanilla `<select>` :-/ . Any other workaround/solution?

**EDIT2** starts looking like a bug to me, filed [Bootstrap issue #24251 - Big dropdowns are unusable when used inside an `overflow:scroll` container, due to being constrained inside it](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24251).

TL;DR image:

[image: b-dropdown stuck in overflow:scroll div]

Thanks .

Comment: has this been solved? i have the same problem

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but on x axis. Did you found a solution ?